# Do i save time when requesting page via ajax and excluding non ajax parts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, performance

I am implementing page loading through `ajax()` and I would like to know if I can save some time when requesting a page through the jQuery function `.get()`

When running the `.get()` function I pass a parameter that will indicate to my PHP page that it is being requested by AJAX and that it should return only those parts that are marked as such.

For example, all my PHP pages have `header` and `footer` functions, so when these pages are called by my AJAX function, the `header` and `footer` functions will be skipped.

Will this save my any time and bandwidth in my `.get()` request and thus delivering the page faster? If not, is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: It will save time in the fact that less HTML will be transferred in the returned data, yes. If you want to save even more time and bandwidth, return a serialised format, such as JSON, and build the HTML on the client. This will reduce the request size even further.

Comment: it will save bandwidth, but likely take more time if you are stripping the header/footer from existing files. however, both effects will likely be minuscule. if your store fragments that don't need processed and don't have extra info, that's the most efficient. also, if you can store them directly as html file fragments instead of loading them via php, your server will do a better job caching and gzipping the static content, which could make it a lot smaller _and_ faster.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answers, I will have to decide which way to go. Is it faster if I build the HTML page with JSON as @RoryMcCrossan pointed out rather than what dandavis suggested? Because I am way to dependent on PHP and would cause me too many troubles delivering HTML pages instead of PHP.

Comment: You don't build a page "with JSON". You can't build a page without HTML. JSON is a data format that allows you to *populate* your page with data. By going the JSON route, you're looking at a templatized model, where you have a templating system (angular, handlebars, etc) that receives JSON objects asynchronously and outputs them as populated HTML. In my experience its complex and  slower to set up, but very good for efficiency since all the output work is transferred from the server to the client. It's probably the "best" approach, but thats dependent on your users, tech, & many other factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, "probably".
It depends on two things:

1) The efficiency of your back-end.
2) The speed of the network.

If your back-end is very slow, and your network speed is high, then you potentially will take a performance hit if it takes longer to create this "custom" version of your request than it otherwise would have. My guess is, though, that it won't, assuming your back end architecture is set up to put together component parts. If you have less component parts, in theory requesting only specific parts of the page should take less time to prepare the request. If you're sort of reverse-engineering things to remove component parts from an existing page/content set, then you might see a drawback. But, efficiency on the server side usually lies in database requests, etc, the kind of thing that usually happens no matter what kind of request you make.

If your network is slow and you don't have a bottleneck on the server side, then you'll definitely be seeing an increase in speed (though probably negligible).

All in all, however, unless you're delivering a half-meg of code per request (which in my experience is only true with bloated frameworks and enterprise-level platforms), then you're really not going to see a difference either way. HTML is a text-based format and the real things that impact your load times are requests for images, video, and other assets like that.

Another way to do this is rather than requesting HTML, you could request JSON. That means that you'd be only getting the content that makes up the page, and having javascript update it client-side as it comes in. This is much more complicated, but will make your application seem much faster.

I recommend the only-get-what-you-need approach (which seems to be what you're doing), however if you're in a startup where you have a funding runway to worry about, I'd say, "Get it done now, optimize it later".

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer dudewad, I am in between of requesting only the parts I need or requesting JSON and build it from there with a templating system as you pointed out. The page has to remain functional if it is accessed by users with javascript disabled. By the way, I am not in a startup and I want to optimize my site to deliver it to my users the best way possible taking into account its actual framework.

Comment: I used to be much like you in that I wanted it to work "everywhere". You might find, though, that from a business perspective that makes no sense. Give it some hard thought, this coming from somebody who used to swear by the moniker that it should work everywhere. Get some metrics on how many of your users have JS disabled, because it'll be a lot smaller than you think. Then you can decide whether or not you want to code for it. Also, keep in mind, your site will *already* break if JS is disabled. You're using jQuery. Sooooo.. :)

Comment: Well, as of now, yes  I am using jQuery but the site works perfectly without it. I have fallbacks for every instance in case user has javascript disabled. However, after some reading, I am thinking about using angular js and ditching support for users without js. It is going to be a lot of work so I have not decided what to do yet. I forgot to mention that I am using wordpress. Thanks again dudewad.

Comment: I just made up my decision and I will go with Angular JS, the more I read about it, the more I love it. Thank you for amplifying my knowledge spectrum.

Comment: Not a bad choice :) keep in mind, Angular 2.0 is coming out relatively soon and you won't be able to "upgrade" to it. You'll have to rewrite almost your entire application. Food for thought, it made a bunch of people angry, but all it really means is that your application runs on angular 1.[whatever].x instead of 2.x

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I also read that version 2 will drop support for older browsers. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, they only will be supporting "evergreen" browsers.
This is important when making your decision. I'm even now seeing IE9 support to start to drop for major clients (think blue-chip companies). You should consider it. The cost of developing to support those old browsers is enormous for a relatively low yield, but that is entirely dependent on your demographic.

Comment: I do have to study my ins and outs for going with version 2. At worst, I will go with version 1 and then in the future, decide whether to upgrade to version 2 or another js framework.